# Getting result of dynamic SQL into a variable for sql-server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, dynamic-sql

Executing dynamic SQL as follows in Stored Procedure:

```
DECLARE @sqlCommand nvarchar(1000)
DECLARE @city varchar(75)
SET @city = 'London'
SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customers WHERE City = @city'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlCommand, N'@city nvarchar(75)', @city = @city
```

How do I use the count(*) column value as return value in the SP?

Answer (score 254, accepted):

```
DECLARE @sqlCommand NVARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @count INT
DECLARE @city VARCHAR(75)
SET @city = 'New York'

SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT @cnt=COUNT(*) FROM customers WHERE City = @city'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlCommand, N'@city nvarchar(75), @cnt int OUTPUT', @city = @city, @cnt = @count OUTPUT

SELECT @count
```

Comment: +1: You beat me to it, need to declare a variable, and mark it as an OUTPUT.  [For more info, and a recommended read for SQL Server dynamic SQL, see The curse and blessings of dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#sp_executesql)

Comment: Thank you. The OUTPUT keyword in N'@city nvarchar(75),@cnt int OUTPUT' was what I was missing.

Comment: Is there no solution that doesn't require adding an output variable to the dynamic statement???

Answer (score 5):

dynamic version

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ReseedTableIdentityCol](@p_table varchar(max))-- RETURNS int
    AS
    BEGIN
        -- Declare the return variable here
       DECLARE @sqlCommand nvarchar(1000)
       DECLARE @maxVal INT
       set @sqlCommand = 'SELECT @maxVal = ISNULL(max(ID),0)+1 from '+@p_table
       EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlCommand, N'@maxVal int OUTPUT',@maxVal=@maxVal OUTPUT
       DBCC CHECKIDENT(@p_table, RESEED, @maxVal)
    END


exec dbo.ReseedTableIdentityCol @p_table='Junk'
```

Answer (score 2):

You've probably tried this, but are your specifications such that you can do this?

```
DECLARE @city varchar(75)
DECLARE @count INT
SET @city = 'London'
SELECT @count = COUNT(*) FROM customers WHERE City = @city
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @sqlCommand nvarchar(1000)
DECLARE @city varchar(75)
DECLARE @cnt int
SET @city = 'London'
SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT @cnt=COUNT(*) FROM customers WHERE City = @city'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlCommand, N'@city nvarchar(75)', @city = @city
RETURN @cnt
```

Comment: I think your answer got cut off.

Comment: Msg 137, `Must declare the scalar variable "@cnt".` 
Msg 178, `A RETURN statement with a return value cannot be used in this context.`. A nice piece of work, bro ))

Answer (score -1):

this could be a solution?

```
declare @step2cmd nvarchar(200)
DECLARE @rcount NUMERIC(18,0)   
set @step2cmd = 'select count(*) from uat.ap.ztscm_protocollo' --+ @nometab
EXECUTE @rcount=sp_executesql @step2cmd
select @rcount
```

Comment: @rcount always give 0 as result

Answer (score -2):

```
 vMYQUERY := 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ALL_OBJECTS WHERE OWNER = UPPER(''MFI_IDBI2LIVE'') AND OBJECT_TYPE = ''TABLE'' 
    AND OBJECT_NAME  =''' || vTBL_CLIENT_MASTER || '''';
    PRINT_STRING(VMYQUERY);
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  vMYQUERY INTO VCOUNTTEMP ;
```

Comment: This doesn't apply for sql server.