# PL/SQL Extract Column Names and use in select statment

Tags: oracle, plsql

not sure if this is possible at all but im trying to do this with as little manual work as possible.

I have a table with 150 columns based on different combinations of factors. 
I wish to extract the column names where a certain certain string is inside the column name.

I have done the following which does this. This is a basic example of what I have

```
  --Create the table 
    Create Table temp
    (id number,
    Fac1_Fac2_Fac_3_Fac4_Fac5 number,
    Fac1_Fac6_Fac_3_Fac4_Fac5 number,
    Fac1_Fac6_Fac_7_Fac4_Fac5 number,
    Fac1_Fac9_Fac_3_Fac4_Fac5 number,
    Fac1_Fac10_Fac_3_Fac4_Fac5 number,
    Fac1_Fac2_Fac_3_Fac11_Fac5 number,
    Fac1_Fac2_Fac_3_Fac4_Fac12 number,
    Fac13_Fac2_Fac_3_Fac4_Fac5 number);

    Insert into temp Values (1,35634,3243,343,564,56,4635,3,334);
    Insert into temp Values (2,3434234,3243,343,564,56,435,3,34234);
    Insert into temp Values (3,5555,3243,33,564,56,435,3,3434);
    Insert into temp Values (4,34234,343,343,564,56,4335,3,34);
    commit;

    --Extract Column Names 
    Select * from (
                  Select COLUMN_NAME 
                  from user_tab_cols 
                  where lower(table_name) ='temp'
                  )
    where column_name like '%FAC13%'

    --This is what I want to automate.
    Select id, FAC13_FAC2_FAC_3_FAC4_FAC5 
    From temp

--I want the column name to come fron the select statment above as there may be lots of names.
```

Basically, I want to select all the rows from my table that have Fac13 in the column name all in one query if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think you can do that in one query. First, your `extract column names query` can be simplified to one query as a cursor, and then use a dynamic select statement as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE proc_dyn_select IS
CURSOR c1 IS 
                  SELECT column_name 
                  FROM user_tab_cols 
                  WHERE LOWER(table_name) ='temp' and column_name LIKE '%FAC13%';

cols  c1%ROWTYPE;
sqlstmt  VARCHAR2(2000);

BEGIN
   OPEN c1;
     LOOP
         FETCH c1 into cols;
         EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
         sqlstmt := sqlstmt ||cols.column_name||',';
      END LOOP;
   CLOSE c1;
   sqlstmt := 'select '||substr(sqlstmt, 1, length(sqlstmt)-1)||' FROM temp';
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlstmt;

EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('error '||sqlerrm);
END;
/
```

**Explanation**

First, the cursor will store the columns that meet your conditions (to be from the table `temp` and the column names have the sub string `FAC13`. Then in execution section (after `BEGIN`), you will build your query dynamically using columns names stored in the cursor `c1`. With each round of the loop, a column name is added as a string and concatenated with a comma. So a string of columns will be built like this `'col1, col2, col3, ... coln,'`. The string is stored in sqlstmt variable.

After the loop end, you amend the string to build sql statement, by adding the keywords `SELECT`, `FROM` and table name. However, we remove the last character of the `sqlstmt` variable, as it is an extra comma.

`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` statement, will run the query stored in `sqlstmt`.

By using a procedure, you can always pass parameters, such that this procedure can perform any dynamic sql statement you want.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance but do you mind explaining roughly how this works?

Comment: @GrantMcKinnon I tried to explain as much as possible. Hope this helps

Comment: thanks that helps, does this run for you though? I keep getting a 'missing or invalid option' error for the cursor portion of the query

Comment: @GrantMcKinnon I've just tested it with small table on 11g sql developer. It is working.

Comment: could it be due to that I am using PL/SQL Developer? I am also using 11g so not sure why this isnt working

Comment: I've also added Procedure to the start, so its Create or replace procedure ... this runs but returns nothing. It looks right to me, just doesn't seem to accept the first block of code. At least when I run it all

Comment: @GrantMcKinnon I'm not sure how to debug on PL/SQL Developer. I've added exception section to the procedure to display error. Notice, the procedure in its current version, will not return anything. It will only run the query. You can update the query to insert the result to some other table. However, if you want to display the results of the query right away, you might need to look at displaying dynamic queries result such as [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14528853/how-to-output-result-of-select-statement-which-is-executed-using-native-dynamic)