# Dynamic SQL Output variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Please see the SQL code below:

```
declare @Classification as varchar(5)
set @Classification =''
declare @ClassificationSQL as nvarchar(4000)
set @ClassificationSQL=''

declare @cnt int
declare @counts int

DECLARE NicheDeletionOffenderCursor CURSOR FOR  
    select classification from dbnicheoffenderclassificationlookup
    Open NicheDeletionOffenderCursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM NicheDeletionOffenderCursor INTO @Classification

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
    BEGIN
    If @ClassificationSQL=''
        set @ClassificationSQL='classification like ' + char(39) + '%' + @Classification + '%' + char(39)
    else
        set @ClassificationSQL=@ClassificationSQL + ' OR classification like ' + char(39) + '%' + @Classification + '%' + char(39)
    FETCH NEXT FROM NicheDeletionOffenderCursor INTO @Classification
    END
CLOSE NicheDeletionOffenderCursor 
DEALLOCATE NicheDeletionOffenderCursor 

SET @ClassificationSQL = 'select count(*) as cnt from person where id=903 and (' + @ClassificationSQL + ')' 

EXECUTE sp_executesql @ClassificationSQL, N'@cnt int OUTPUT', @cnt=@Counts OUTPUT
```

How do I assign the count output from @ClassificationSQL to a variable to use in the next part of the TSQL?

Comment: Uh, `SELECT @cnt = count(*) from person...` all kinds of things wrong here. Why not `dbo.person`? Why `@cnt` and `@counts`? Why does the case differ? Why no `N` prefix on the 2nd last line?

Comment: I am new to dynamic sql.  I borrowed some code from the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840730/getting-result-of-dynamic-sql-into-a-variable.  I could be completely wrong with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things to mention here:

1. No need to declare the variable used inside of the dynamic sql (i.e. `@cnt`) outside of it (i.e. at the top)
2. No need for a cursor as a simple `SELECT @var = @var + column` construct will concatenate
3. With no cursor, there is no need to declare the variable used with it (i.e. `@Classification`)
4. Single-quotes can be escaped by using two of them (i.e. `''`). However, it could simply be preference to use `CHAR(39)` instead as some people find it to be more readable.
5. Setting a variable in dynamic SQL is just like regular SQL (i.e. `SELECT @var = expression FROM...`)

End result:

```
DECLARE @ClassificationSQL NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @Counts INT

SET @ClassificationSQL = COALESCE(@ClassificationSQL + N' OR ', '')
                            + N'classification LIKE ''%'
                            + classification
                            + N'%'''
FROM dbnicheoffenderclassificationlookup

SET @ClassificationSQL =
      N'SELECT @TempCount = COUNT(*) FROM person WHERE id = 903 AND ('
    + @ClassificationSQL
    + N')'

EXECUTE sp_executesql
    @ClassificationSQL,
    N'@TempCount INT OUTPUT',
    @TempCount = @Counts OUTPUT

SELECT @Counts
```

Answer (score 0):

See a below sample about how you can get the output of a dynamic query (tested in SQL Server 2008 R2). Actual post from where the idea is taken [How to get sp_executesql result into a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803211/how-to-get-sp-executesql-result-into-a-variable)

```
DECLARE @retval int;   
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(500);
DECLARE @Param nvarchar(500);

DECLARE @table nvarchar(50)  
SELECT @table = N'newperson'  

SELECT @SQL = N'SELECT @retvalOUT = MAX(salary) FROM ' + @table;  
SET @Param = N'@retvalOUT int OUTPUT';

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, @Param, @retvalOUT=@retval OUTPUT;

SELECT @retval;
```

You can make changes to your procedure accordingly.

Comment: what is @retvalOUT? Please make me understand... this @retvalOUT is not declared and still working..