# cannot transfer value from a variable to another variable

Tags: sql, variables, dynamic

I have a problem when I would like to transfer the value of a variable to another variable.

```
declare @column varchar(255);
set @column = 'cheesecake';

declare @tmp varchar(255);
set @tmp = (select @column from TEST where id = 1);
```

But in this case `@tmp` won't have the value of the table, but the name of the `@column` variable. I tried it with dynamic sql, but I got a syntax error.

```
declare @column varchar(255);
set @column = 'cheesecake';

declare @tmp varchar(255);
set @tmp = exec('select ' + @column + ' from TEST where id = 1');
```

How can I solve that the `@tmp` variable would contain the value of the query?

Comment: what syntax error did you get?

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'exec'.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting result of dynamic SQL into a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840730/getting-result-of-dynamic-sql-into-a-variable)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

AFAIK, it is not possible to directly assign to a variable using `exec. A workaround to your issue would be to create a table variable to store the results of the dynamic query, and then set the value of the second variable using the table variable, like so:

```
declare @column varchar(255);
set @column = 'cheesecake';

declare @tmp varchar(255); 
declare @query nvarchar(255) = N'select ' + @column + N' from TEST where id = 1'

declare @tbl table(tmp varchar(255)) --Intermediate Table variable

insert into @tbl --Insert dynamic query results here
exec sp_executesql @query

select top 1 @tmp = tmp from @tbl --Assign value here

select @tmp
```

EDIT: I stand corrected. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840730/getting-result-of-dynamic-sql-into-a-variable) answer shows how you can assign from dynamic SQL result to a variable by making use of `OUTPUT` parameters within the dynamic query.

Answer (score 1):

EXEC executes in a different context, therefore the variables cannot be shared without hassle. You specify an output parameter to the statement using [`sp_executesql`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)

```
DECLARE 
  @language nvarchar(255),
  @translation nvarchar(255), 
  @statement nvarchar(255)
SET @language = N'norwegian'
SET @statement = 'select @translation='+@language+' from Translations where id = 1'
EXEC sp_executesql 
  @statement, 
  N'@translation nvarchar(255) OUTPUT', 
  @translation OUTPUT
SELECT @translation
```

[<kbd>**SQLFiddle**</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/11434/8)

Comment: This seems to be the better way. OP should ideally accept this one, if he bothers to check back.