# Call SQL stored proc with OUTPUT param from another stored proc

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters, output

It seems very simple solution, but I can't figure it out. Please help.

I have to call a stored proc with OUTPUT param from another stored proc. I think one of the issues is dynamic SQL, but I don't know how else to write it since @SQLWhere will change dynamically within C# code.

This is the proc being called from another proc:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_RetrieveTotalRecord]
@SQLWhere AS NVARCHAR(1000),
@TotalRecordsFound as varchar(16) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @SQL AS NVARCHAR(Max)
    SET @SQL='Select @TotalRecordsFound = Count(Table_ID)  
    From TableName Where ' + @SQLWhere 
    EXEC(@SQL)  
    return
END
```

Here is how I am calling it from another proc:

```
Declare @TotalRec AS NVARCHAR(16);
Declare @SQLWhere AS NVARCHAR(1000);
SET @SQLWhere='Date Between ''12/13/2016'' AND ''12/14/2016'''
EXECUTE  USP_RetrieveTotalRecord @SQLWhere, @TotalRec output;
```

Here is the error I am trying to resolve:

```
Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Line 30
Must declare the scalar variable "@TotalRecordsFound".
```

Comment: Ignoring the nightmare this could be for SQL injection, you need to parameterise your dynamic query to include output. EDIT: The answer here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840730/getting-result-of-dynamic-sql-into-a-variable-for-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you have a 2nd SP, just use one like so:

```
Declare @TotalRec AS NVARCHAR(16);
Declare @SQLWhere AS NVARCHAR(1000);
SET @SQLWhere='Date Between ''12/13/2016'' AND ''12/14/2016'''
 SET @SQL='Select @TotalRecordsFound = Count(Table_ID)  
    From TableName Where ' + @SQLWhere 
 EXEC(@SQL)
```

Or use date variables if that's all you are using for selection (no dynamic sql necessary) - unless this is just a simplified example

--- comment section is broken, so, in response to get a value out, use something like this:

Ok - the simplest way is to use sp_ExecuteSQL

```
Declare @result int
Declare @sql nvarchar(max)
SET @SQL = ' SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable'

exec sp_ExecuteSQL @sql, N' @Result int Output', @Result output

select @result as MyCount
```

Comment: DaveN, You are right that this is a simplified version. There can be 1 to many criteria for WHERE clause. Actually, we don't need another proc. I agree with you. But how do I use @TotalRecordsFound  in another 'Select' that follows.

Comment: Also, I need count in form of variable and not field that is why using @TotalRecordsFound, since I have to do calculation in next step

Answer (score 0):

Don't do what you are trying to do, Only pass values to stored procedure and then build the dynamic sql inside your procedure, something like ......

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_RetrieveTotalRecord]
   @StartDate   DATE = NULL
  ,@EndDate     DATE = NULL
  ,@TotalRecordsFound INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(Max);
    SET @SQL = N' Select @TotalRecordsFound = Count(Table_ID) '
             + N' From TableName Where 1 =1 '
             + CASE WHEN  @StartDate IS NOT NULL THEN 
               N' AND [Date] >= @StartDate ' ELSE N' ' END
             + CASE WHEN  @EndDate IS NOT NULL THEN 
               N' AND [Date] <= @EndDate ' ELSE N' ' END

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL  
                      ,N'@StartDate DATE, @EndDate DATE, @TotalRecordsFound INT OUTPUT'
                      ,@StartDate 
                      ,@EndDate
                      ,@TotalRecordsFound OUTPUT
END
```

Now `@EndDate` and `@StartDate` variables are optional , depending on what variable values you pass procedure will build the dynamic sql accordingly and return the results.

Also using parameterised query with `sp_executesql` will protect you against a possible SQL-Injection attach and also your proc will benefit from parameterised execution plans.

Comment: M. Ali, I have to use send @SQLWhere from .NET code since it being built based on a number of selections. However, one thing I see is that you are using EXEC sp_executesql . I can try that. Please let me know how will you call this proc  USP_RetrieveTotalRecord from another stored proc?

Comment: @Silverfish well just get the values from your application layer , try not to build t-sql in your application code. Also pass valid `Date` values to your procedure so you can avoid implicit conversions and benefit from indexes on the table.

Answer (score 0):

M. ali, thanks for your help, but we have all SELECT, WHERE, and GROUP by criteria being passed from the application after dynamic selections. I needed a quick fix. 
Finally I was able to resolve the issue using a temp table. I know they are not recommended, but I tried using Common table expression, table variable, but the @TotalRecordsFound was not visible outside the dynamic SQL. Therefore, created temp table, Inserted data into it using dynamic SQL, and then joined it with the next select statement.