# How to use parameters in select query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, sql-server-2008-r2

I have table :

Table Name : tbl_Income

```
EmployeeID      Element      FinancialYear   Jan    Feb    Mar

00402060         Basic         2016-2017     100    200    300
00402060         HRA           2016-2017     100    200    300
00402060         DA            2016-2017     100    200    300
```

In which i want to fetch data from tbl_Income.

In which i fetch below problem.

```
Declare @Month varchar(10) = 'Jan'

select @Month  from tbl_Income where  EmployeeID = '00402060' and Element = 'Basic' and  FinancialYear = '2016-2017'
```

I want to below Output

```
OUTPUT : 

   Jan
1  100
```

Please help me...

Comment: You'll have to do that with dynamic SQL. This isn't a very good database design, by the way.

Comment: You can use case statement to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Dynamic SQL like this:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
Declare @Month varchar(10) = 'Jan'
declare @income int

set @sql = 'select @inc=' + @Month + ' from tbl_Income where  EmployeeID = ''00402060'' and Element = ''Basic'' and  FinancialYear = ''2016-2017'''

exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@inc int OUTPUT', @inc=@income OUTPUT
select @income as income
```

Beware though that this is open to SQL Injection attack.

You'd be better off fixing your design.

Comment: how to store this output '100' value in variable?? please help me..@GurV

Comment: can u check my answer i stored that value in one varible..@DhavalPurohit

Comment: @Chanukya - Your answer is exactly the same as mine. Dhaval - Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840730/getting-result-of-dynamic-sql-into-a-variable-for-sql-server)

Comment: Yes this is same answer...Mr.GurV  I want to store this output value in one single variable like "declare XVariable decimal(18,2) " and now i want to this output store in XVariable...

Comment: @GurV he wrote select query but i did this in dynamic query please check

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @Month varchar(10) = 'Jan'
declare @v nvarchar(max)
declare @v1 INT
set @v =CONCAT('select @v1=' ,@month, ' from 
table_a where  EmployeeID = ''00402060'' and Element = ''Basic'' and  FinancialYear = ''2016-2017''') 
PRINT @V
EXECUTE sp_executesql @v,N'@V1 INT OUTPUT', @V1=@V1 OUTPUT;  
SELECT @V1;
```

Answer (score 1):

[Sample Database Design][1]

*[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vxEb.png
-- table "dbo.Month"*

```
    CREATE TABLE dbo.Month (
  Id int NOT NULL,
  Name nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_Month PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id)
)
```

-- table IncomeType"

```
    CREATE TABLE dbo.IncomeType (
  Id int NOT NULL,
  Name nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_IncomeType PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id)
)
```

-- table "FinancialYear"

```
    CREATE TABLE dbo.FinancialYear (
  Id int NOT NULL,
  YearSpan nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_FinancialYear PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id)
)
```

-- table "Employee"

```
   CREATE TABLE dbo.Employee (
  Id int NOT NULL,
  Name nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_Employee PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id)
)
```

-- table "Income"

```
    CREATE TABLE dbo.Income (
  Id int NOT NULL,
  EmployeeId int NOT NULL,
  TypeId int NOT NULL,
  YearSpanId int NOT NULL,
  MonthId int NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_Income PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id)
)
```

--Alter Each Table to add foreign key references

```
ALTER TABLE Income
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Income_Employee FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeId) REFERENCES Employee (Id)

    ALTER TABLE dbo.Income
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Income_FinancialYear FOREIGN KEY (YearSpanId) REFERENCES dbo.FinancialYear (Id)


    ALTER TABLE dbo.Income
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Income_IncomeType FOREIGN KEY (TypeId) REFERENCES dbo.IncomeType (Id)

    ALTER TABLE dbo.Income
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Income_Month FOREIGN KEY (MonthId) REFERENCES dbo.Month (Id)
```

1. EmployeeID will come from the Employee table
2. Element    will come from the income type table
3. FinancialYear    --from the financial year table
4. MonthId from the months table

Now a simple join can help you get each value using the foreign key references