# Conversion of DateTime

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have the following query:

```
set @DataEnd = '
          select top 1 datetime 
          from IntradayHistory.dbo.IntradayDataHistory' + @product + ' 
          where TickerID = ' + cast(@ticker as nvarchar(24)) + ' 
          order by datetime desc
'
exec(@DateEnd)
```

This should return me only 1 value, and it did:

[image]

However, as I would need that value as a DateTime for dynamic query, how should I do it?

Comment: I have tried to add this in my CTE table: `where stime <= ''' + convert(nvarchar(max),@DateEnd,121) + '''` But to no avail too.

Comment: And also I have tried this: `stime <= 'exec(@DateEnd)'`

Comment: Can you provide [sample data and expected output](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)?  Often it's easier to answer a question when we have some data to play with.

Comment: @destination-data hi, I do not exactly have sample data but more so I would like to:

`declare @DataEnd as datetime

set @DataEnd = '
          select top 1 datetime 
          from IntradayHistory.dbo.IntradayDataHistory' + @product + ' 
          where TickerID = ' + cast(@ticker as nvarchar(24)) + ' 
          order by datetime desc'`

reason is because I know that the query would give me only 1 datetime result.

Comment: I think I understand.  Are you trying to store `Date Time` in a var for use later on?  If so take a peek at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840730/getting-result-of-dynamic-sql-into-a-variable-for-sql-server).

Comment: Hey @destination-data, you got it! However, I am still unclear on how to use the answer :/ Could you assist me?

Comment: @destination-data THANK YOU SO MUCH AS WELL (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql) you can send an output parameter to your dynamic query.

```
DECLARE @sqlCommand NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @dateEnd DATETIME;
SET @sqlCommand = '
          select top 1 @retVal = datetime 
          from IntradayHistory.dbo.IntradayDataHistory' + @product + ' 
          where TickerID = ' + cast(@ticker as nvarchar(24)) + ' 
          order by datetime desc
';
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlCommand, N'@retVal DATETIME OUTPUT', @retVal=@dateEnd OUTPUT;
SELECT @dateEnd;
```

**Option B:**

You can use temp table to store the result of dynamic query.

```
DECLARE @sqlCommand NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @sqlCommand = '
      select top 1 datetime 
      from IntradayHistory.dbo.IntradayDataHistory' + @product + ' 
      where TickerID = ' + cast(@ticker as nvarchar(24)) + ' 
      order by datetime desc
';
CREATE TABLE #temp1 (Result DATETIME);
INSERT INTO #temp1 EXEC (@sqlCommand);
SELECT * FROM #temp1;
```

Comment: Hi, I tried what you have shared, however, I got the error: `Msg 214, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp_executesql, Line 21
Procedure expects parameter '@statement' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'`

Comment: @fauxpas you are missing one character there between `x` and `c`

Comment: Sorry, I replaced the error, with the new one, noticed that too!

Comment: I got another error, after replacing the character: `Msg 214, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp_executesql, Line 21 Procedure expects parameter '@statement' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'` and should the result I get be NULL?

Comment: have you used `NVARCHAR(MAX)` for sql statement?