# How to use a variable on a table name?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SET @tab = 'tableName'

SET @field1 = (SELECT field1 FROM '+@tab+' WHERE colName IS NULL)
```

I'm getting this error:

> Must declare the table variable "@tab".

I need to set the result on @field1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Table name as variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838490/table-name-as-variable)

Comment: Which database?

Comment: You have to use dynamic SQL in any database.  The specific syntax varies by database.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please dd the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: Tag properly!!!!  Which dbms is this????  It's useless if someone gives you a solution to the wrong dbms.

Comment: Thanks for all help. I'm using SQL Server. This is a small part of a transact sql.

Answer (score 0):

For a SQL Server database, use `EXECUTE sp_executesql` to run the dynamic sql you setup.  (Notice the correct placement of the quotes compared to your post).

```
SET @tab = 'tableName'
SET @field1 = 'SELECT field1 FROM ' + @tab + ' WHERE colName IS NULL'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @field1
```

However, to save the return value you should look into defining `OUTPUT` as shown in this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/3840771/9392034

Comment: Sorry guys. I'm using SQL Server. This is a small part of a transact sql.

Comment: @SergioPaiva - I've updated the answer to indicate that it is for SQL Server.